# Is it possible to get the domain or ip address if the request came from?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, security

I am trying to put security in the controller , by checking the domain or ip address from the request and compare it to the domain that is save in the database. But I'm having a problem on how to get the client ip address. I'm using spring-boot java . Is there anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Have you tried `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` ?

Comment: Yes , but if we check the ip address of the PC that do the request using ipconfig in cmd  then compare it is different.

Comment: Note that if there's a proxy in between you'd most likely get that proxy's ip address. The original client ip could be found in the [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header - if it is set by the proxy.

Comment: ahh thank you so much , I already tried that one but it returns null. Do you have a sample code ?

Comment: Let us know what have you tried. it would be much easier for us to tell you.

Comment: We already tried request.getRemoteAddr() and request.getRemoteHost(), also this @RequestHeader final HttpHeaders headers but still not working. I was thinking also that getting the domain by passing it in the request from the front end but I think it is not a good idea.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'. The methods you have cited are those you would use. What is the expected vs the actual result?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is getting the real ip address of the client.

Comment: I'm aware of what you are trying to do. What is the *expected*  result and what is the *actual* result  because the methods mentioned elsewhere in these comments are the only ones available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help

```
public static String getRequester(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String forwardHeader= request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if (forwardHeader == null) {
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    } else {
        return new StringTokenizer(forwardHeader, ",").nextToken().trim();
    }
}
```

Reference 2 - https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/

Reference 1 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For